# Transferring a WordPress website from Mamp

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I have been working on my WordPress site locally (Mamp) and have now ftp'd the wp-content folder to my live web address on 123-reg.

The site works fine on 123-reg and I have imported all of my plugins, posts and images.

The problem I have and what I have been trying to work out is how to transfer all of my plugin settings from my local version to the live version. I know I could renter all of the plugin details on the live site, however I have created contact forms etc in some of the plugins and don't really want to renter all of the fields etc.

I have exported the SQL file from the local version too, although I am not sure where or how I import this into the new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be simple if you use phpmyadmin. I know you said you got the database, but I will cover that step too.

Let's start from scratch. Copy your wp_content folder. Delete the contents of your wp_content folder on the remote server.

Don't go to the site yet, first go to your local phpMyAdmin (http://localhost/phpmyadmin/) then export the local database. When exporting, make sure you are exporting the whole database, not just a specific table. The saved file should be named after your database and not something like wp_posts.sql.
Secondly, go to your hosted site's phpMyAdmin, select all the tables in your WP database and drop them.

Yes, you will be deleting the database on your site(example of table names that you should be dropping: wp_posts, wp_taxonomy, wp_users, etc. Then just use the import feature and browse to your saved database. Then you will be able to go to the site and login as you did on the local. The plugin settings should be all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the WordPress Codex's page on [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) is a good idea, but I've had great luck with [Duplicator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/).  It's a fantastic plugin that worked for me with very few hiccups.

Here's part of their description:

> The Duplicator plugin is designed to give WordPress Administrators the
>   ability to migrate a site from one location to another location in 3
>   easy steps. Just create a package, download it and install. No need to
>   change all your settings and re-run import/export scripts. The plugin
>   also serves as a simple backup utility.